# Type Mismatch error in ADODB.Connection code

Tags: runtime-error, adodb, type-mismatch

I have made a code to send data from excel to access as its a repetitive task in my office. I do not know VBA, i have copied this code from internet and have made modifications whereever required. However, its throwing Run Time Error 13 Type Mis Match Error. I am very upset with this error, please see if you guys can help. Thanks in advance. Code is below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

'set up connection string
cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\anurag85678\Desktop\Tracker\Database2.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"

'connect to database
cn.Open

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

rs.Open "Test", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable

With rs
.AddNew
.Fields("ID") = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
.Fields("Name") = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")
.Fields("Process_Name") = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1")
.Fields("Companies_Done") = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1")

.Update
End With

' Close the recordset and connection
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Best Regards,
Anurag

Comment: Did you add a reference to *Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects* ?

Comment: Many thanks for your response Alex K. No, i was not adding a reference to activeX data object. I have little knowledge of VBA but i have over a period of 1 month learnt few things and could manage a solution myself. Much appreciate your interest in solving the problem and many apologies to respond so late. I want to paste the solution code here but unable to do so due to words limitation.